# Solving complex linear congruences

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Find $x \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that:

$(1+2i)x \equiv 1 \mod 3+3i$

How would you go about doing this? Best I can think of is keep guessing....

Comment: $(1+2i)(1-2i)=1^2+2^2=5\implies (1+2i)^{-1}=\frac{1-2i}5$

Comment: Is the 3+3i inside brackets, subject to the MOD ?

Comment: yeah i guess so

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\ $ mod $\, 3(1\!+\!i)\!:\,\  0\equiv 3(1\!+\!i)(1\!-\!i) \equiv 6 \,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{5\equiv -1}\,\ $ so, rationalizing denominators
 $$\, x\equiv \dfrac{1}{1\!+\!2i}\equiv \dfrac{1\!-\!2i}{\color{#c00}5} \equiv -1\!+\!2i$$

Written explicitly $\quad \begin{eqnarray} (2i\!+\!1)(2i\!-\!1) &=\,& 1 + \color{#0a0}{3(i\!+\!1)}(i\!-\!1)\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\color{#0a0}{3(i\!+\!1)}} \\  {\rm via}\quad {-}4-1\ &=\,& 1+3(-2)\end{eqnarray}$

Remark: The point of rationalizing the denominator is that it transforms the problem of dividing by an $ $ *irrational* $ $ number $\,(1\!+\!2i)\,$ to the *simpler* problem of dividing by a $ $ *rational* $ $ number $(\color{#c00}5).\, $ To invert $\,5\,$ mod $\,w = 3\!+\!3i,\,$ it suffices to invert it mod any integer multiple $\, n = wv,\,$ since

$${\rm mod}\ n\!:\ 5j\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ 5j = 1\! +\! nk = 1\! +\! wvk\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\ w\!:\ 5j\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\, j \equiv 1/5$$

We chose the obvious integer multiple $\, n = 3(1\!+\!i)(1\!-\!i) = 6.\,$ Any integer mutiple coprime to $\,5\,$ will do the trick, e.g. we could also use the norm $\,n = ww' = (3\!+\!3i)(3\!-\!3i) = 18.$

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Could you explain the steps?

Comment: @user1066113 Are you familiar with rationalizing denominators? Which steps are not clear?

Comment: Yes I get the rationalizing part. I think I rushed a little with asking this question. To be honest I don't even quite get how to find a modulus of a number when working with complex numbers. Like how do you find 5 mod 3+3i? I'm going to play around with these, and I think that should make things a little clearer for me :)

Comment: But to answer the question. I don't get why you want to multiply 3+3i by 1-i and why knowing that 5 =-1 and having 5 as a denominator helps us. EDIT: trying to figure out what's 10 mod 3+3i. Lol I'm going full potatoe on this one.

Comment: @user1066113 I added a remark explaining the motivation.